# Notify jquery plugin working only one time on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I am using notify jquery plugin, it is working normally on all browsers, but on IE it is displayed only the first time and then it keeps giving me the below error

this is the plugin i am using http://notifyjs.com/ and i am calling it that way `$.Notification.notify('error', 'left middle', 'Error', 'Please try again later !!');`

[image]

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - Need to see an example of how you're using the plugin.

Comment: @Twisty i have editted my question please check

Comment: Which version of IE? because this plugin have some notes about IE versions: look: https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications

Comment: Also, can you post some code? I tried one of the examples on their site in a few different versions of IE, and it worked fine.

Comment: this question is really simple actually. but no 1 try to answer. why? 1. your error message is very clear so we can fixed this easly. 2. U not give us IE version which throw error, even i believe it was IE 8 which isn't support `containts`. 3. No notifyjs version given, cz i not see same code in the notifyjs source code (possible u use the old one), cz your code tells that its writen for jquery but the original written on pure js. 4. no fiddle 5. give bounty to your question isn't make people can help you, it just make your question more visible for several days only.

Comment: i am using IE 11, and i am using the same jquery plugin that is in the link in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using a older version of their code. If you look at the below blame

https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/blame/7191c17e26097b9617071c72f1a409f2dcbc68ea/dist/notify.js

[image: Code blame]

You can see the code has `document.body.contains` while your JS has `document.contains`. And it was changed 2 years ago for IE only. So you need to use the latest file from below

https://github.com/jpillora/notifyjs/blob/master/dist/notify.js